# My Mac seems to be using some sort of Proxy or VPN without my knowledge

Tags: networking, macos, proxy

I am using OSX El Capitan 10.11.2.

I first noticed a problem when Netflix wouldn't allow me to watch videos because it thought was using a VPN, which I'm not. Upon further investigation, I found that when I look up my external IP address (by Googling "What's my IP"), my computer has an IP address with a geolocation in a different state from where I am. Additionally, my internet connection is at least 50% slower than it normally is (measured using speedtest.net).

When I do the same from my phone, on the same wifi network, I find a different IP address that's in the correct geolocation. Also, when I tether my computer to my phone, so that it's on an entirely different network and ISP, I have the same problem on my computer. So I know the problem is not with my Wifi router or my ISP, but with my computer.

I did not have this issue with Netflix 12 hours ago, but I don't know for sure whether my IP address was doing this 12 hours ago, because I had no reason to check. The only thing that's happened to my computer in the last 12 hours is that I rebooted it for the first time in perhaps a few months.

I've used a VPN once before, about a year ago, but I've since uninstalled that software.

UPDATE: At the suggestion of Apple support, I booted my computer into safe mode. The problem did not exist in safe mode.
I tried logging in to the guest account (not in safe mode), and the problem did exist.
And finally, I noticed that the problem does not start until a few moments after startup. So if I check my IP immediately after startup, it's what I would expect, but less than a minute later, it changes to the problematic other IP address.

Comment: Have you ever installed proxy software, such as Tunnel Bear? If so, have you made sure you cleared it out as thoroughly as you could?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: No, I have never installed such software.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the VPN software I used months ago: PrivateTunnel. I thought I had uninstalled it after this problem began, but I missed some files. After some research, I found what needed to be deleted, and that solved the problem.

I still have no idea why PrivateTunnel suddenly starting causing this problem, since I did not attempt to uninstall, update, or even use PrivateTunnel in the last few months, and I am almost certain that I have rebooted my computer more than once since the last time I did.

I found the problem by looking at Activity Monitor, under the network tab. The process using the most data was "ptcore", which, after Googling it, I found to belong to PrivateTunnel. Earlier in this troubleshooting process, I "uninstalled" PrivateTunnel by deleting the application from the /Applications folder, which, as it turns out, is not the proper way to uninstall it. I found the proper process [here](https://www.privatetunnel.com/index.php/kb-installinguninstalling/175-kb-how-to-uninstall.html).

I would love if anyone had some suggestions for why PrivateTunnel started doing this, but since I've solved the problem, that's not particularly urgent, and I don't think it warrants posting a separate question about it.

Comment: Wait, so what's the question now? I thought you just explained what was causing your issue.

Comment: Yeah, in hindsight it seems obvious that my answer was very vaguely worded. Sorry about that. I found that PrivateTunnel is what caused the issue, but I'm now curious as to why PrivateTunnel suddenly started causing the issue _now_, despite me not doing anything with PrivateTunnel in the last few months.

Comment: The link is not available now, future readers can use http://web.archive.org/web/20150512204227/https://www.privatetunnel.com/index.php/kb-installinguninstalling/175-kb-how-to-uninstall.html.